# Dragon Quest 8 Skills

Tags: dragon-quest-series

After each level, skill points are awarded that can be added to 5 skill buckets.
For example, the Hero has:
Sword
Spear
Boomerang
Fist
Courage

I have been dividing my points equally among all of the skills except fist.
So if I get 4 points +1 to all skills except fist.

Would I be better off specializing my skills more?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In addition to the abilities unlocked, throwing more points into a single skill allows you to acquire the trait bonuses sooner.  For example, you get progressively bigger bonuses to sword attacks at 4, 22 and 66 points in Sword Skills.  Likewise, dumping into Courage will net you 3/4 MP spellcasting and 1/2 MP spellcasting at 56 and 90 points, respectively.

So, if you want to focus on a certain play style (i.e. spellcaster) or weapon type, it is advantageous to specialize.

Answer (score 2):

On my playthrough, I had enough skill points to end up with high scores in 2-3 skills per character.  I suspect that trying to evenly balance four skills is going to spread you thin, leaving you a bunch of abilities that you can't use (due to having the wrong weapon equipped) and denying you the most powerful abilities.

Another consideration is that several of the most powerful weapons are mutually exclusive (since you have to use one up in the alchemy pot to get another), so if you're interested in the most powerful party possible, you might want to avoid specializing in the following skill pairs:

> - spears and boomerangs
> - axes and hammers